# How to move all characters of strings on x coordinate on console

Tags: c#

I'm developing a console application which draws shapes, the proof of concept that I'm trying is with a square. I'm looking for a way to move the square smoothly to the right in this case. I had a solution that did that, however it was flickering. What I want is some solution that allows me to move the square without the flickering. I'm doing this for fun, and little by little, write a custom console game engine, for learning purposes. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm not using GDI+ or system.drawing yet, I'll add that later. Here's some code:

```
static void DrawRectangle()
{
    int height = 10; //height of square
    int width = 20; //width of square
    int coordinateY = height - 1;
    int coordinateX = width - 1;
    int firstPositionY = 0; //to track cursor position in Y
    int firstPositionX = 0; //to track cursor position in X
    char[][] c = new char[height][];
    //buffer of console. Be aware that the shape to be drawn isn't larger than the actual console buffer
    Console.BufferHeight = 30;
    Console.BufferWidth = 120;
    //Font and background color
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    //Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    //Formula to start drawing in the center of the buffered console
    firstPositionX = (Console.BufferWidth - width) / 2;
    firstPositionY = (Console.BufferHeight - height) / 2;
    //set initial cursor position to the results of the above calculation
    Console.Beep();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX, firstPositionY);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        c[y] = new char[width];
    //draws top line of the square
    c[0][0] = '\u2554';
    Console.Write(c[0][0]);
    for (int x = 1; x < width; x++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        c[0][x] = '\u2550';
        Console.Write(c[0][x]);
    }
    for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        //keeps track of the cursor, so it draws vertically
        Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX, firstPositionY + y);
        c[y][0] = '\u2551';
        Console.WriteLine(c[y][0]);
    }
    //Set cursor position to the other side top right of the square
    Console.SetCursorPosition(width + firstPositionX, firstPositionY);
    c[coordinateY][coordinateX] = '\u2557';
    Console.Write(c[coordinateY][coordinateX]);
    for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(width + firstPositionX, firstPositionY + y);
        c[y][coordinateX] = '\u2551';
        Console.WriteLine(c[y][coordinateX]);
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX, firstPositionY + height);
    for (int x = 0; x <= coordinateX; x++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        c[coordinateY][x] = '\u2550';
        Console.Write(c[coordinateY][x]);
    }
    //square corners
    Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX, firstPositionY + height);
    Console.Write("\u255A");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX + width, firstPositionY + height);
    Console.Write("\u255D");
    //fill the square with solid blocks
    for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX + 1, firstPositionY + y);
        for (int x = 1; x < width; x++)
        {
            c[y][x] = '\u2588';
            Console.Write(c[y][x]);
            Thread.Sleep(7);
        }
    }
    //pass matrix to string for easier handling? Will fix later
    string s = string.Empty;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            s += c[y][x];
        s += "\n";
    }
    while (true)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Thread.Sleep(3);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(firstPositionX += 1, firstPositionY);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see code that draws a square. Please post the code that isn't working...

Comment: Also, the `DrawLine` method does not draw a line, it draws a square..?

Comment: Stop coupling your UI and model code; that is going to cause you tremendous problems when you try to port it to another UI like WinForms or UWP. Create a `Square` (or `Shape` or `Sprite` or something) class and let your UI draw them. Your `Square` or whatever class should only store and modify the model, not have any drawing or timing code in it.

Comment: Yes, originally it draw a line, then I made it draw a square. I want to move the square when an arrow key is pressed. As to the code being messy, I know, I'll separate it after I get past the current hurdle. This is just me prototyping and see if it's posible to do. The code that doesn't work as expected is when you try to move the square. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here's a way to draw a rectangle on the screen and then move it when the user presses one of the arrow keys (you would still need to add logic to keep the rectangle within the bounds of the console window).

Note the perf could be improved by only "erasing" the parts of the original rectangle that don't overlap with the new rectangle, but at least it's a start on moving a rectangle around. Also, I don't see any flashing when I run it on my machine.

```
static void DrawRectangle(Rectangle rect, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Blue, 
    char fill = '█')
{
    var foreColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(rect.Left, rect.Top);

    for (int i = 0; i < rect.Height; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(new string(fill, rect.Width));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(rect.Left, Console.CursorTop + 1);
    }

    Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
}     

private static void Main()
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    // Draw a rectangle
    var rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 5);
    DrawRectangle(rect);

    // Move the rectangle when the user presses an arrow key
    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for a key press
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) ;

        // "Erase" the current rectangle
        DrawRectangle(rect, Console.BackgroundColor);

        // Set the location for the new rectangle based on the key that was pressed
        switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            {
                var location = new Point(rect.X, rect.Y - 1);
                rect = new Rectangle(location, rect.Size);
                break;
            }
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            {
                var location = new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + 1);
                rect = new Rectangle(location, rect.Size);
                break;
            }
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
            {
                var location = new Point(rect.X - 1, rect.Y);
                rect = new Rectangle(location, rect.Size);
                break;
            }
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
            {
                var location = new Point(rect.X + 1, rect.Y);
                rect = new Rectangle(location, rect.Size);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Draw the new rectangle
        DrawRectangle(rect);
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: I think this might be it. Yes, what I want is to move the rectangle on key press. I'll try it and let you know. After this, I'm cleaning the code. Thanks!

Comment: I only see flickering when filling the rectangle, but better than I had. If I remove the fill and draw the shape empty, it doesn't flicker. Thanks for your help